# List out of range error in my code in Django. When i go to download a pdf file

Tags: python, django, index-error, indexoutofrangeexception

I want to download a patients pdf file but when i click in download button this error is come. Please anyone can help me about this error ..

views.py

```
def download_pdf_view(request,pk):
 dischargeDetails = PatientDischarge.objects.all().filter(admitted=pk).order_by('-id')[:1]

 dict = {
    'assign_doctor': dischargeDetails[0].assign_doctor,
    'admitted': dischargeDetails[0].admitted.patient_name,
    'phone': dischargeDetails[0].admitted.phone,
    'address': dischargeDetails[0].admitted.address,
    'symptoms': dischargeDetails[0].admitted.symptoms,
    'release_date': dischargeDetails[0].release_date,
    'medicine_cost': dischargeDetails[0].medicine_cost,
    'other_charge': dischargeDetails[0].other_charge,
    'days_count': dischargeDetails[0].days_count,
    'room_bill':dischargeDetails[0].room_bill,
    'total_bill': dischargeDetails[0].total_bill,


}
return render_to_pdf('hospital/pdf_template.html',dict)
```

models.py:

```
class PatientDischarge(models.Model):
    assign_doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    admitted = models.ForeignKey(Admitted, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    release_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
    medicine_cost = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    other_charge = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.admitted.patient_name if all([self.admitted, self.admitted.patient_name]) else 0

    def days_count(self):
        return self.release_date - self.admitted.admited_date if all([self.admitted, 
        self.admitted.admited_date]) else 0
```

Comment: It appears that the given patient hasnt been discharged. You should include the error stack trace and what research/attempts you've done to try and fix this yourself

Answer (score 0):

Without the complete stacktrace is difficoult to understand the issue.

But, Looks like that `dischargeDetails` is empty and when you try to access with `dischargeDetails[0]` it raise the error `IndexError: list index out of range`. Check if this line of code `PatientDischarge.objects.all().filter(admitted=pk).order_by('-id')[:1]` is actually return something

A simple python example to explain it:

```py
my_list = []
print(my_list[0])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Plus please don't call your own variable with type names, for example use another name for your `dict` variable since is a python type

```
a = dict
print(type(dict))
<class 'type'>
```

Comment: Be sure that this  `dischargeDetails = PatientDischarge.objects.all().filter(admitted=pk).order_by('-id')[:1]` is actually returing something, plus you have to handle the exception by putting the whole dict in a `try` and then return an error to the frontend.